# UWP/MVVM: a child UserControl's ViewModel.Model inherited from a parent's ViewModel.Property

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, uwp, parent-child, datacontext

My question after a bit of code/XAML...

**Models**

```
public class Login {
    public Login() {
        Email = "john@gmail.com";
        Password = "password";
    ]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public Customer() {
        Name = "John Smith";
        Phone = "(000)000-0000";
        Login = new Login();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Login Login { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class LoginViewModel {
    public LoginViewModel(Login login) {
        Model = login;
    }
    public Login Model { get; set; }
    public string Email { 
        get => return Model.Email; 
        set => Model.Email = value; 
    }
    public string Password { 
        get => return Model.Password; 
        set => Model.Password = value; 
    }
}

public class CustomerViewModel {
    public CustomerViewModel(Customer customer) {
        Model = customer;
    }        
    public Customer Model { get; set; }
    public Login Login {
        get => return Model.Login;
        set => Model.Login = value;
    }
    public string Name { 
        get => return Model.Name; 
        set => Model.Name = value; 
    }
    public string Phone { 
        get => return Model.Phone; 
        set => Model.Phone = value; 
    }
}
```

**Views**

```
<local:LoginView>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<local:LoginView>

<local:CustomerView>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <local:LoginView/>
</local:CustomerView>
```

**CustomerView.cs**

```
public sealed partial class CustomerView: UserControl {
    public CustomerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new CustomerViewModel(new Customer());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an instance of LoginView declared in CustomerView and what I need is to bind LoginView.ViewModel.Model to CustomerView.ViewModel.Login; This is not an actual use case. It's only meant to illustrate the parent-child binding relationship.  I need to be able to bind a property of a parent View's ViewModel to the Model of a child View's ViewModel.

I could create a child ViewModel in the parent View's ViewModel and then bind it to the DataContext of the child View, but that gets messy quickly with complex ViewModels. I would prefer to simply pass down Properties of parent's to become the Models of it's children.

I can figure this out, eventually, but having spent a few days pouring through online posts and reading books and tutorials, I am ready to ask for help.

Comment: You're not going to like the answer but you should put the child view model into the parent's and then bind that to the user control. It's the most straightforward way to do it. Other options are hackier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think you're probably right.